# Using Throw exception in two functions in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am using VS 2013 and coding in c#

My first function, calls the second function with 4 argument and the second one return type is void.
sometimes second functions gives an exception and program crashes.
I want to pass it's exception to the first function so that it could write it in a message box.

Is this possible? (And if it is, how I should do that?)
Thanks.

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: try { Foo(a,b,c,d); } catch(Exeption ex) { ... }

Comment: Thanks to both of you. the link was very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap call to the second function into `try/catch` block and handle the exception being thrown by that function:

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
public void FirstFunction()
{
   ....
   try
   {
        SecondFunction();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
        // here is text of exception being thrown in SecondFunction
        string errorText = ex.Message; 
   }
}
```